# Remove parent div class if child div has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 37px; height: 36px;">
   <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button">16</button>
</td>
```

Check button value if it is 16 then remove the `.CalendarDay--valid` from the parent div.

How do I do this?

Comment: i tried but that is(my code) worst code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent` with `this` for particular `td`. I give two `td` 16 -- 17 on example.17 is shown but 16 remove.

```js
$('.CalendarDay').find('.CalendarDay__button').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '16')
    $(this).parent('td').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 37px; height: 36px;">

      <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button">16</button>
    </td>
    <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 37px; height: 36px;">

      <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button">17</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest()` method to do that:

```js
var elem = $('.CalendarDay__button');
if (elem.text().trim() === '16') {
  elem.closest('.CalendarDay--valid').removeClass('CalendarDay--valid');
}
```

```css
.CalendarDay--valid button{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 37px; height: 36px;">

      <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button">16</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have multiple buttons to check:

```js
$.each($('.CalendarDay__button'),function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var parent = btn.closest('.CalendarDay');
    // Before
    console.log(parent.attr('class'))
    if(btn.text() == "16"){
        parent.removeClass('CalendarDay--valid');
        // After
        console.log(parent.attr('class'))
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 37px; height: 36px;">

      <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button">16</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```